# Meaning of ギャップ in the following sentence

Tags: meaning, words, katakana, animals

Context: a couple is checking out the otters while visiting an aquarium.

> Boy: 苗代【なえしろ】はカワウソが好きなの？
>
> Girl: うん！動物で一番好き。食べる時とか時々ブサイクになる**ギャップ**がたまんないの。

What is the meaning of ギャップ in this sentence? Since she says "食べる時", I think maybe she is referring to the "gap" of an otter's slightly open mouth, but I am not sure. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scpr5.jpg) you can see the whole page. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's from English "gap". She is referring to the large difference of an otter's face between when it's not eating and when it's eating. I guess she regards the former face as "handsome/cool" and the latter face as "relaxed and cute, although goofy in a sense". ブサイク is normally a negative word, but it's not always negative at least to some young girls...

Related:

- [KIMOKAWAII: BOTH CUTE and GROSS AT THE SAME TIME](https://www.tofugu.com/japan/kimokawaii/)
- [What is gap moe?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/28922/5094)
- [ブサカワ](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%83%96%E3%82%B5%E3%82%AB%E3%83%AF) (ブサイク + かわいい)

  > 不細工だが可愛いと感じられる顔立ちや表情を形容する表現。(snip)たとえば犬種のパグなどはブサカワであり、ブサカワであることがむしろ愛好されている種といえる。

Answer (score 5):

I think the "ギャップ" is used as more of a colloquial usage than [dictionary usage](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/54402/meaning/m0u/). I found the [link](https://tokitoma.jp/?p=202016) : "かわうそファンが6年かけて発見！可愛いすぎる４つのポイント"

I borrow the different sentence how "ギャップ" is used from the site. The excerpt is

> 個人的にはアクリル板をカリカリする仕草がツボです。かわうそのやんちゃさが良く出ています…！
>   しかも、可愛いだけではないのがかわうそのすごいところ！水中をカッコよく泳いだり、時には**野性味たっぷりに魚にかぶりついたり**。さっきまで、**あんなに可愛くしていたくせに…**！でも、この**ギャップ**がかわうその魅力なんです。

I guess the author wants to describe in a same way. They always seem to behave cute and cool, but when it comes to eating they don't mind eating brutally. I think she wants to call the change of behaviors as a "ギャップ" rather than open of mouth.

Normally they are used in a positive way like "[ギャップに萌える](https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%82%AE%E3%83%A3%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E8%90%8C%E3%81%88)".